# How do I flatten my soil to apply gravel?

Tags: gravel

I have dug up a section of my lawn to apply gravel. The soil is now very lumpy and I am wondering how to flatten it out?

Comment: Are you talking about the area where the gravel bed will be? Or do you want to break up the soil that you dug up so that you can spread it out somewhere else?  Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 4):

Get a pair of wellies on, a rake and a spade. Rake it as level as you can, use the spade to bash any larger lumps, and then walk all over it, not missing even an inch - this should break up the clods and also reveal any soft, sunken parts. Now rake it again and walk over it again, repeat if necessary. I hope this area isn't absolutely huge... otherwise its a machine with a roller on it. Not to be done if its currently waterlogged or frozen, wait for conditions to improve if that's the case.